# Allowing only a single page view for guest user, using Devise on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, account, user-accounts

I'm trying to implement a feature where a user invites friend to the site, and the invited person will land on the page and view that page, but then when trying to view another page by clicking on a link, it asks them to sign up.

I was thinking about using Devise timeoutable and setting the session to 1.second for guest users. So it would be something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable

  def timeout_in
    if self.guest? 
      1.second
    end
  end
end
```

Is this the correct way of handling this type of situation? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can add authenticate_user! in your ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ......................

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

And skip the filter for the page you want guests to visit.

Comment: interesting idea, but the reason I'm trying to do this is because I want them to view one page, and then immediately asked to sign up. So the only page they will be able to see is the first landing page. I don't know how I can achieve it using this approach though

Comment: Then you mean the landing page could be a random page that the guest's friend give the link to him?

Comment: Yes, but not a "random" page, but for example I could share a post and you could read it once. But after that when you try to navigate away you can't, you have to sign in.